# How to debug my application in Linux with my Android mobile?

Tags: android, debugging

How can I debug my Android application in a mobile, not in the emulator?

My OS is Linux. When I try to connect with my mobile device for debugging, it is not 
responding.

Comment: is it showing in your device tab as ???????????? like this

Comment: which device your using to debug

Answer (score 8):

This question is answered in the documentation for debugging against a mobile 
device: *[Using Hardware Devices](http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/device.html)*.

Directly quoted from their documentation:

---

1. Declare your application as "debuggable" in your Android Manifest.
   In Eclipse, you can do this from the **Application** tab when viewing the Manifest (on the right side, set **Debuggable** to *true*). Otherwise, in the `AndroidManifest.xml` file, add `android:debuggable="true"` to the `<application>` element.
2. Set up your device to allow installation of non-Market applications.
   On the device, go to **Settings > Applications** and enable **Unknown sources** (on an Android 4.0 device, the setting is located in **Settings > Security**).
3. Turn on "USB Debugging" on your device.
   On the device, go to **Settings > Applications > Development** and enable **USB debugging** (on an Android 4.0 device, the setting is located in **Settings > Developer** options).
4. Set up your system to detect your device.

   - <snip - Not using Windows or Mac OS X>
   - If you're developing on Ubuntu Linux, you need to add a [udev](http://www.kernel.org/pub/linux/utils/kernel/hotplug/udev.html) rules file that contains a USB configuration for each type of device you want to use for development. In the rules file, each device manufacturer is identified by a unique vendor ID, as specified by the `ATTR{idVendor}` property. For a list of vendor IDs, see [USB Vendor IDs](http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/device.html#VendorIds), below. To set up device detection on Ubuntu Linux:

     1. Log in as root and create this file: `/etc/udev/rules.d/51-android.rules`.
        Use this format to add each vendor to the file:
        `SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ATTR{idVendor}=="0bb4", MODE="0666", GROUP="plugdev"`

        In this example, the vendor ID is for HTC. The `MODE` assignment specifies read/write permissions, and `GROUP` defines which Unix group owns the device node.
        **Note**: The rule syntax may vary slightly depending on your environment. Consult the `udev` documentation for your system as needed. For an overview of rule syntax, see this guide to [writing udev rules](http://www.reactivated.net/writing_udev_rules.html).
     2. Now execute:
        `chmod a+r /etc/udev/rules.d/51-android.rules`

You can verify that your device is connected by executing `adb devices` from your SDK `platform-tools/` directory. If connected, you'll see the device name listed as a "device."

If using [Eclipse](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eclipse_%28software%29), run or debug your application as usual. You will be presented with a **Device Chooser** dialog that lists the available emulator(s) and connected device(s). Select the device upon which you want to install and run the application.

If using the [Android Debug Bridge](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_Debug_Bridge) (ADB), you can issue commands with the `-d` flag to target your connected device.

Comment: i did like above but after executing last command chmod a+r /etc/udev/rules.d/51-android.rules it is showing no such file / directory found

Comment: @Narendra: Did you try `sudo chmod a+r /etc/udev/rules.d/51-android.rules`?  Also, are you running Ubuntu?  And does the file you created contain the `.` at the end that I accidentally hilighted when I copied the text?  If so, start over from that step and don't include the `.` - I edited the instructions to fix that error :)

Comment: no only this command "chmod a+r /etc/udev/rules.d/51-android.rules" wait i m trying.

Comment: i did like "sudo chmod a+r /etc/udev/rules.d/51-android.rules", also showing same problem

Comment: @Narendra: You *created* that file, so it should exist.  Did you add a `.` to the end of the filename on accident (as I accidentally instructed you to do)?  Check through that directory (`ls`) and see what files *do* exist.

Comment: i didnot add ,can u tell me under which root i create the above directory and file

Comment: @Narendra: `/etc/udev/rules.d/51-android.rules` is an absolute path from the file system root under unix-like operating systems (linux).  The initial `/` means "from the root of the drive...".  As for "I did not add" - Then make sure you follow all the steps in order.  See in particular step #1.

Answer (score 4):

**[Setting up a Device for Development](http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/device.html)**

Set up your device to allow installation of non-Market applications.

1. On the device, go to *Settings* > *Applications* and enable Unknown sources (on an Android 4.0 device, the setting is located in *Settings* > *Security*).
2. Turn on "USB Debugging".
3. On the device, go to *Settings* > *Applications* > *Development* and enable USB debugging (on an Android 4.0 device, the setting is located in *Settings* > *Developer* options).
4. Set up your system to detect your device.

If you're developing on Ubuntu Linux, you need to add a udev rules file that contains a USB configuration for each type of device you want to use for development. In the rules file, each device manufacturer is identified by a unique vendor ID, as specified by the `ATTR{idVendor}` property. For a list of vendor IDs, see USB Vendor IDs, below. To set up device detection on Ubuntu Linux:

1. Log in as root and create the file `/etc/udev/rules.d/51-android.rules`.
2. Use this format to add each vendor to the file:

   ```
   SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ATTR{idVendor}=="0bb4", MODE="0666", GROUP="plugdev"
   ```

In this example, the vendor ID is for HTC. The MODE assignment specifies read/write permissions, and GROUP defines which Unix group owns the device node.
Note: The rule syntax may vary slightly depending on your environment. Consult the udev documentation for your system as needed. For an overview of rule syntax, see this guide to writing udev rules.

Now execute:

```
chmod a+r /etc/udev/rules.d/51-android.rules
```

Comment: i did like above but after executing last command chmod a+r /etc/udev/rules.d/51-android.rules it is showing no such file / directory found

Comment: open this /etc/udev/rules.d/ folder and check 51-rules files are there

Comment: sudo chmod a+r /etc/udev/rules.d/51-   press tab to select your android rules file and press enter.

Answer (score -1):

On Android 4.2 and newer, **Developer options** is hidden by default. To make it available, go to **Settings** > **About phone** and **tap Build number seven times**. Return to the previous screen to find Developer options.